# Can't tag docker image after successfully create image using docker-compose build (Error response from daemon)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, deployment

```
PS C:path> docker-compose up --build      
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
...
...
```

I assume this is successful,

```
PS C:path> docker-compose ps
NAME                IMAGE                    COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
kafka               wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         kafka               2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
mysql               mysql:latest             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
zookeeper           wurstmeister/zookeeper   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   zookeeper           2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp
```

```
PS C:path> docker tag backend:latest xxx.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/backend:latest
Error response from daemon: No such image: backend:latest
```

When I run `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
mysql                                      latest    c71276df4a87   8 days ago      565MB
ambassador/telepresence-docker-extension   1.0.8     bb2143440bbd   2 weeks ago     528MB
ambassador/telepresence-docker-runtime     1.0.8     a1a178ca4417   2 weeks ago     21.3MB
redis                                      latest    0ec8ab59a35f   2 weeks ago     117MB
postgres                                   15.2      bf700010ce28   5 weeks ago     379MB
docker/welcome-to-docker                   latest    b1eb53af308a   7 weeks ago     13.6MB
wurstmeister/kafka                         latest    a692873757c0   12 months ago   468MB
wurstmeister/zookeeper                     latest    3f43f72cb283   4 years ago     510MB
```

Comment: The `docker images` output in fact does not show a `backend` image.  What should cause it to exist?  Instead of just including diagnostic outputs, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially the `docker-compose.yml` fragment that `build:` the image?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the image exists first.
The command below is possible to list the images.

```
docker images
```

After that, you can tag the image and push that to a remote repository.

```
docker tag backend:latest xxx.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/backend:latest && docker push xxx.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/backend:latest
```

Comment: `Error response from daemon: No such image: segmentation_service:latest`

Comment: Try to run the cmd **docker images** and check the images.

Comment: question already edited